# What is an efficient way to divide clock by 1000 or more?

Tags: integrated-circuit, clock

Context: This is a home brew project that incorporates NO microcontrollers as a learning exercise. I need to time something up to 20 seconds long, down to the nearest 100th of a second, and display the time interval measured. I'm using a 4 digit 7 segment common cathode led for the display.

I have a 100khz crystal and I want to display the tens, ones, tenths, and one hundredths of seconds (ie 23.36 seconds) on a 4 digit 7 segment led display. I thought I could use the 4026 chip, a decimal counter and led driver. However I have to chain 3 of them just to get to 100hz, then chain another 4 of them to get the 4 digits of display. 7 ICs (plus multiplexing logic because the display uses common abcdefg leads, plus resetting etc) seems like a LOT.

Am I missing a much simpler way to approach this? The 'rules' are: any ICs or other components but no software (no MCUs).

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a CPLD.

Comment: If accuracy isn't important, a plain binary counter could do the job. Dividing by 2^10 is approximately dividing by 1000 (1024 to be precise). http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/66436/INTERSIL/CD4060.html

Comment: Over 20 seconds that would be 2048 "missed" cycles equalling 2 hundredths of a second (0.02048 seconds) by my calculation. Not bad! I was hoping for millisecond accuracy - I'll hold out for another option but I may use this, thank you!

Comment: Or a tiny microcontroller. I'd go for a ATtiny13, just because I have them lying around, but there are even smaller ones that can do the job perfectly well.

Comment: @jippie Except that the OP explicitly said *no MCUs*.

Comment: Henry, binary divider will not miss cycles. With suggested binary divider you get single output pulse for every 1024 input pulses, and with a thousand divider you get a single output pulse for every 1000 input pulses. That would mean that after 20 seconds your maximal counting error would be just 1024 in case of binary divider, or 1000 in case of thousand decade divider. You see, difference is just 24 pulses over 20 seconds in worst case. If you count 123 pulses over 1 sec with binary divider, you would display 125952 Hz (123 x 1024) on your display. Decade divider is just more human readable.

Comment: Ah, yes... and if you need more precision then 2^10 then you stop the counter and read all lower bits with your MCU. That would give you a single pulse precision. That feature is a benefit of a counter over dedicated divider (which usually has a benefit of allowing higher frequencies).

Comment: @avra - he said no microcontrollers. Twice.

Comment: @stevenh: So, "read all lower bits with your MCU" becomes "read all lower bits". Once. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple. You can find ICs that will divide the 100 kHz by 1000, like the [74HC4059](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4059_CNV.pdf) programmable divide-by-N counter, but most of these will cost you an arm and a leg, where a couple of cheap [74HC390](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT390_CNV.pdf) counters will do. The HC390 is a dual BCD counter, so for the second you only need half of the IC, but it's cheaper than a single BCD counter.

Comment: I like the idea of keeping it simple, I didn't realize there were dual decade counters like that, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

If you want to implement a circuit like what you describe using off-the-shelf chips, I would estimate that it would take three decade counter chips (two of which will be used for divide-by-five, and one for divide-by-four), two 74HC595 chips (shift register with latch), one 74HC374 (8-bit latch), a segment driver chip, some transistors and resistors to drive five LED-digit commons, and probably about 3-4 miscellaneous "glue logic" chips (quad NAND, quad XOR, etc.)

The basic circuit looks something like [this](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#%24+3+5.0E-6+10.20027730826997+50+5.0+50%0A168+400+88+400+72+1+20%0A155+272+96+288+96+1+0.0%0Aw+448+376+400+392+0%0Aw+448+360+400+376+0%0Aw+448+344+400+360+0%0Aw+448+328+400+344+0%0Aw+448+312+400+328+0%0Aw+448+296+400+312+0%0Aw+448+280+400+296+0%0Aw+448+264+400+280+0%0Aw+448+248+400+264+0%0Aw+448+232+400+248+0%0Aw+448+216+400+232+0%0Aw+448+200+400+216+0%0Aw+448+184+400+200+0%0Aw+448+168+400+184+0%0Aw+448+152+400+168+0%0Aw+400+152+448+136+0%0Aw+400+136+448+120+0%0Aw+400+120+448+104+0%0Aw+400+104+448+88+0%0Aw+448+392+456+392+0%0Aw+456+392+456+64+0%0Aw+376+56+344+56+0%0A154+344+88+400+88+1+2+5.0%0Aw+344+80+344+56+0%0Aw+344+96+320+96+0%0A150+320+64+224+64+1+2+0.0%0Aw+344+56+320+56+0%0Aw+320+96+320+72+0%0A152+224+96+272+96+1+2+0.0%0Aw+224+64+224+88+0%0A163+80+296+104+296+1+4+0.0+5.0+0.0+0.0%0A163+168+176+184+176+1+5+0.0+0.0+5.0+0.0+0.0%0AR+248+208+272+208+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0AR+144+328+168+328+0+0+40.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0Aw+96+280+96+192+0%0A150+120+104+176+104+1+2+0.0%0Aw+248+152+120+152+0%0Aw+120+152+120+112+0%0Aw+120+96+104+96+0%0Aw+104+96+104+248+0%0Aw+168+192+96+192+0%0Aw+80+312+80+408+0%0Aw+272+112+272+144+0%0Aw+272+144+288+144+0%0Aw+288+144+288+408+0%0Aw+400+408+288+408+0%0Aw+288+408+80+408+0%0Aw+176+104+224+104+0%0AR+80+408+40+408+1+2+1000.0+2.5+2.5+0.0+0.5%0A168+464+344+480+344+1+4%0Aw+464+392+456+392+0%0Aw+464+376+448+376+0%0Aw+464+360+448+360+0%0Aw+464+344+448+344+0%0Aw+512+392+528+392+0%0Aw+512+376+544+376+0%0Aw+512+360+544+360+0%0Aw+512+344+544+344+0%0Aw+464+408+464+424+0%0Aw+464+424+192+424+0%0Aw+96+280+112+264+0%0Aw+112+264+192+264+0%0Aw+192+264+192+424+0%0Aw+248+152+248+160+0%0Aw+104+248+144+248+0%0Aw+144+248+144+280+0%0A152+424+56+376+56+1+2+5.0%0Aw+424+64+456+64+0%0A150+496+48+448+48+1+3+0.0%0Aw+448+48+424+48+0%0Aw+496+40+496+24+0%0Aw+496+24+320+24+0%0Aw+320+24+320+72+0%0Aw+496+48+528+48+0%0Aw+496+56+512+56+0%0Aw+512+56+512+344+0%0Aw+528+48+528+392+0%0A162+544+344+600+344+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+544+360+600+360+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+544+376+600+376+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+544+392+600+392+1+2.1024259+1.0+0.0+0.0%0Ar+600+344+616+344+0+100.0%0Ar+600+360+616+360+0+100.0%0Ar+600+376+616+376+0+100.0%0Ar+600+392+616+392+0+100.0%0Aw+616+344+616+360+0%0Aw+616+360+616+376+0%0Aw+616+376+616+392+0%0Ag+616+392+616+408+0%0Aw+544+392+528+392+0%0A); as illustrated, it would run off 20Khz rather than 100Khz, but a decade counter wired as divide-by-five would easily fix that.

The LEDs flash digits in the order 1000ths 100ths 10ths units tens.  Although in this schematic I use a 20-bit latch with outputs fed back to inputs, it would be easier to use a shift register chip for 16 of the bits.  The shift register chip (74HC595) would also offer the benefit of including a free output latch (equivalent to the one in the lower right).

If one were to omit the "AND" and "OR" gate near the top-right of the schematic, it would count in binary.  Each bit is the xor of itself and the previous carry, and the new carry should be the "and" of the previous carry and the previous bit, except that on the first bit each "frame" the carry should be forced on.  Very simple logic which allows for any length increment to be performed by a shift register.  A slight 'wrinkle' in this variation is that the circuit will latch every four bits (since every four bits will need to be displayed as a decimal digit) and also test whether a latched digit is 9 and a carry is set; in that case, it will "pretend" that the next four bits from the shifter are all 1's, meaning that that digit will wrap to zero and the carry will be live for the next digit.

If one didn't need to display the count values, it might be simpler to just cascade one divide-by-ten counter for each digit.  On the other hand, this circuit offers the advantage of being able to multiplex five digits on a single display driver.  If desired, it could easily be adapted to handle any number of digits, simply by adding more shift registers and adjusting the timing circuitry.

Comment: Thank you for the very comprehensive answer, which coincidentally introduced me to that awesome circuit simulator applet. I don't fully understand the answer yet, but I'll give it a +1 :)

Comment: @Henry: Glad to be of help.  By the way, the applet allows as an undocumented feature the ability to set the size of the "Latch", "Decade Counter", "ADC", "DAC", and a few other things.  If you select "Export" under the file menu, you'll get one line for each wire or part.  The first thing on the line will say what the thing is; most chips, gates, and things will have a number there.  The remainder of the line will describe the particulars of the thing.  In many cases, there will be a parameter indicating the size (even for parts whose size cannot otherwise be edited).  Try changing it...

Comment: ...then hit the "IMPORT" button and see what happens.  Note that some parts like the "Decade" counter include a parameter for each output pin which seems to indicate the initial state; the parameters must be present (one per output) but the values are ignored.  This is important when changing the decade counter to e.g. a divide-by-16; for the device to re-import, one must add six more zeroes (one for each added output).